# How to click a button with input type and value?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a submit button I need to click, page source shows this code for it:

`<input type="submit" value="Submit" />`

I tried typing in:
`WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath( "//input[@type'submit' and @value = 'Submit']"));
         button.click();`

but this does not work, no error but the button is not clicked one I am on the page.

full page source code if anyone requests it for some reason: 
https://justpaste.it/5dal7

I am on mac os using Selenium on Java.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your XPath expression, you should be handling `type` [HTML attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp) the same way as the `value` attribute to wit:

```
//input[@type='submit' and @value='Submit']
```

Demo:

[image]

Translating it to Java code:

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Submit']"));
button.click();
```

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried your answer and it still does not work. Either way, thank you for taking your time to write this.

Comment: It does work as it evidenced by the above screenshot which is based on the code you've posted. It might be the case you need to use an [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) in case if the button is not immediately available in [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). Check out [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) article for comprehensive explanation and code examples

Comment: Made it work on! error in variable names on my part. Thank you!

Comment: If you feel the issue is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking on hallow check mark below the down vote button.